# Order by float field in Django not working

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model and I am trying to order by the highest rating average, but it doesn't seem to do the correct sorting.

In my views.py I have:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all().order_by('-rating__rating_average')
```

my model definition has the field defined as:

```
rating_average = models.FloatField()
```

However, this query seems to return a random sort. Am I overlooking something? How is this query done with a FloatField?

Here is my models.py file with the relevant models:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.OneToOneField('restaurant.Restaurant', primary_key=True)
    one_star_total= models.IntegerField()
    two_star_total= models.IntegerField()
    three_star_total= models.IntegerField()
    four_star_total= models.IntegerField()
    five_star_total= models.IntegerField()
    number_of_ratings = models.IntegerField()
    total_rating_value = models.IntegerField()
    rating_average = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.restaurant.restaurant_name


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2= models.CharField(max_length=100, default= "null", blank=True,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    website_link= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.restaurant_name
```

Comment: It should be working... what are you doing afterwards... ? Can you add more code... try printing all the restaurants returned by query...

Comment: I've tried printing them and it returns an incorrect order. If it is possible to do this query with a FloatField, then I can debug this. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: So... ratings are stored in some other table... ?

Comment: Oh maybe this might be it. rating is not a field within the Restaurant model. There is a OneToOne relationship between the two. The field that I am interested in the Rating model is rating_average

Comment: Yes, ratings are stored in some other table. Does this make a difference in the query?

Comment: It should still work, as long as the relationship is properly defined in model. Try checking the value of `Restaurant.objects.all().order_by('-rating__rating_average').ordered`. Is it `true` or `false` ?

Comment: try doing `Ratings.objects.all().order_by('rating_average')` on your Ratings model.

Comment: It returns the right order. Not too sure why the other query doesn't work.

Comment: Then... I am guessing... you should recheck your Restaurant model definition. I think there may be a problem with relationship definition.

Comment: Please show your actual models.

Comment: Sure thing. I've added the models.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of null values, but because of that, it didn't work for me.

I solved it using the F function by Django to have in count null values, like this:

```
from django.db.models import F

restaurants = Restaurants.objects.order_by(F('rating_average').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Documentation by Django - [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values).